# How to make text flow from left right bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, col

The effect that I'm trying to get is where the text will flow from left to right using colunms in bootstrap. After the twelfth colunm on the first sectin I want to break into a new line hopefully the code will make it clearer.

```
<?php

?>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css"/>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navCollapse">f</button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    FLINTATION LOGO
                </div>



                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navvbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
            "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain wa
            s born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of th
            e great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or 
            avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue 
            or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occas
            ionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take 
            a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some ad
            vantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has n
            o annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="images/amber.png"/>
            <div><br>

            <div id="left">
                <div>
                    But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain wa
                s born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of th
                e great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or 
                avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue 
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
```

> After the amber.png file on the page I want the next div to appear onto a new line starting from the left, instead of right.

Hopefully this can be understood , any questions just ask !

Thanks Jeffrey.

Comment: Could you please share an example of the end result (if you know one), because it's kind of hard to understand what exactly is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper structure including the Bootstrap `.row` and columns

The general structure would be

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img/>
      </div>

      <div id="left" class="col-sm-12"> /* or whatever width */
      </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain wa s born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of th e great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of
      human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occas ionally circumstances
      occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some ad vantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses
      to enjoy a pleasure that has n o annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="left" class="col-sm-12">
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain wa s born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of th e great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
      happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KzvaYV)

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob! Thank you so much Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them into rows. Please see the example jsfiddle

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <img src="images/amber.png"/>here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="left">
                <div>
                    test
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xp2d4wqz/

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap class `row` to separate the sections. Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xp2d4wqz/1/